# Delphi extract string between to 2 tags

Tags: regex, delphi

How would I go about extracting text between 2 html tags using delphi?
Here is an example string.

```
blah blah blah<tag>text I want to keep</tag>blah blah blah
```

and I want to extract this part of it.

```
<tag>text I want to keep</tag>
```

(basically removing all the blah blah blah garbage that comes before and after the `<tag>` & `</tag>` strings which I also want to keep.

Like I said, I am sure this is extremely easy for those who know, but I just cannot wrap my head around it at the moment. Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: Oh, the joys of HTML tag soup - if it were XHTML, you could use a XML parser :)

Comment: Some people, when presented with a problem, decide, "I'll use XML."  Now they have four or five problems!

Comment: If your HTML is not XML, then you cannot reliably parse: it totally depends on the string between the tags, which might have very irregular formatting. If it is HTML, tags themselves might differ in case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This depends entirely on how your input looks.

**Update** First I wrote a few solutions for special cases, but after the OP explained a bit more about the details, I had to generalize them a bit. Here is the most general code:

```
function ExtractTextInsideGivenTagEx(const Tag, Text: string): string;
var
  StartPos1, StartPos2, EndPos: integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
  result := '';
  StartPos1 := Pos('<' + Tag, Text);
  EndPos := Pos('</' + Tag + '>', Text);
  StartPos2 := 0;
  for i := StartPos1 + length(Tag) + 1 to EndPos do
    if Text[i] = '>' then
    begin
      StartPos2 := i + 1;
      break;
    end;


  if (StartPos2 > 0) and (EndPos > StartPos2) then
    result := Copy(Text, StartPos2, EndPos - StartPos2);
end;


function ExtractTagAndTextInsideGivenTagEx(const Tag, Text: string): string;
var
  StartPos, EndPos: integer;
begin
  result := '';
  StartPos := Pos('<' + Tag, Text);
  EndPos := Pos('</' + Tag + '>', Text);
  if (StartPos > 0) and (EndPos > StartPos) then
    result := Copy(Text, StartPos, EndPos - StartPos + length(Tag) + 3);
end;
```

### Sample usage

```
ExtractTextInsideGivenTagEx('tag',
    'blah <i>blah</i> <b>blah<tag a="2" b="4">text I want to keep</tag>blah blah </b>blah')
```

returns

```
text I want to keep
```

whereas

```
ExtractTagAndTextInsideGivenTagEx('tag',
    'blah <i>blah</i> <b>blah<tag a="2" b="4">text I want to keep</tag>blah blah </b>blah')
```

returns

```
<tag a="2" b="4">text I want to keep</tag>
```

Comment: I see what you mean about the formatting and I am sure your code would be great if it were something simple like you said but there are mutliple tags in the same string but the info I want to extract is only between 2 of them. basically the text I am wanting to extract is the embed code of an video which is embedded using the normal `<object>embdding code here</object>` stuff but the string looks more like I showed in the example above with a bunch of garbage in front of and after the `<object> & </object>` tags so not sure how the code could be modified to suit that need and thx for the reply

Comment: @fubar: My third and fourth functions can handle tags before/after  `<tag>` and even malformatted HTML code.

Comment: Sorry about the reply I only saw your first example when I made the reply I will text the others out now thx again all.

Comment: The last code you provided worked wonderfully. I did not even think about the tag parameters which in my case I needed to account for and your example handled it perfectly. 

TYVM,
Fubar

Comment: The for loop can be replaced by posex in D7+. But I assume this has been done on purpose.

Comment: @Marco van de Voort: Yes, that is possible (and would make the code slightly smaller). I am parsing strings very often, and in most cases the task is far more advanced then the one in this problem, and in such cases the `for` loop is the best and most versatile tool. So it is a reflex of mine always to do things manually, simply because the manual approach is the one that works all the time.

Comment: I realize this is an old post, but it seems worth noting that this code will only return the first occurrence of a tag. Nevertheless, thanks for the starter code.

Answer (score 8):

If you have Delphi XE, you can use the new `RegularExpressions` unit:

```
ResultString := TRegEx.Match(SubjectString, '(?si)<tag>.*?</tag>').Value;
```

If you have an older version of Delphi, you can use a 3rd party regex component such as [TPerlRegEx](http://www.regular-expressions.info/delphi.html):

```
Regex := TPerlRegEx.Create(nil);
Regex.RegEx := '(?si)<tag>.*?</tag>';
Regex.Subject := SubjectString;
if Regex.Match then ResultString := Regex.MatchedExpression;
```

Answer (score 3):

you can build an function using the [pos](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.Pos) the [copy](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.Copy) functions.

see this sample.

```
Function ExtractBetweenTags(Const Value,TagI,TagF:string):string;
var
i,f : integer;
begin
 i:=Pos(TagI,Value);
 f:=Pos(TagF,Value);
 if (i>0) and (f>i) then
 Result:=Copy(Value,i+length(TagI),f-i-length(TagF)+1);
end;


Function ExtractWithTags(Const Value,TagI,TagF:string):string;
var
i,f : integer;
begin
 i:=Pos(TagI,Value);
 f:=Pos(TagF,Value);
 if (i>0) and (f>i) then
 Result:=Copy(Value,i,f-i+length(TagF));
end;
```

and call like this

```
StrValue:='blah blah blah<tag> text I want to keep</tag>blah blah blah';
NewValue:=ExtractBetweenTags(StrValue,'<tag>','</tag>');//returns 'text I want to keep'
NewValue:=ExtractWithTags(StrValue,'<tag>','</tag>');//returns '<tag>text I want to keep</tag>'
```

Comment: Notice that `(i > 0) and (f > 0) and (f > i)` is equivalent to `(i > 0) and (f > i)`, because `f > 0` follows from this latter conjunction.

Comment: I tried the code above but it returned some unexpected results such as text after the closing tag was still being displayed but thx for the reply and your time, much appreciated.

Fubar.

Answer (score 3):

I find that this version is more versatile because it isnt limited to one occurence of the tags. It searches for the next endtag after the starttag.

```
Function ExtractBetweenTags(Const Line, TagI, TagF: string): string;
var
  i, f : integer;
begin
  i := Pos(TagI, Line);
  f := Pos(TagF, Copy(Line, i+length(TagI), MAXINT));
  if (i > 0) and (f > 0) then
    Result:= Copy(Line, i+length(TagI), f-1);
end;
```